# KornShell (ksh) redirection

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I have a script which redirects std out/std err as below:

```
SCRIPTS=/test/scripts
LOG=/test/log
echo $SCRIPTS
echo $LOG
$SCRIPTS/dmm_algo_ofac_daily_sched.ksh >> $LOG/test12.log 2>&1
```

This script is not able to expand `$SCRIPTS` and `$LOG`

If I replace it as below:

```
/test/scripts/daily_sched.ksh >> /test/log/test12.log 2>&1
```

It complains as below:

```
: bad file unit numberd/test.ksh: line 33: 1
```

Also I am not able to invoke the script from the directory where it is saved. If I do

`./test.ksh` it gives me error saying file not found. I am able to execute it via `ksh /test/sched/test.ksh` though.

Can someone help me with these. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of ksh, and on what platform? I have no problem with your script using either ksh93 or pdksh on Linux.

Comment: k shell version is ksh93

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm almost certain that the problem is because of DOS/Windows line endings

The error message you are getting is overwriting itself because of a carriage return. You can fix your file using `dos2unix`.

Comment: Yes, this can be often problematic, do a `od -c` to see if you have \r.

Answer (score 1):

Add magic `#!/bin/ksh` to the first line to invoke directly without naming the interpreter on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I'll conjecture wildly that your root cause(s) has (have) nothing to do with redirection.

Is the script you've exhibited /test/sched/test.ksh or /test/scripts/test.ksh?  Are you certain?

Comment: It is /test/sched/test.ksh also the version of k shell is ksh93